# Status strip location appearing below the taskbar in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Here I shared you my output where my main page status strip appearing below the taskbar...please any one can help me out

Comment: How do you set the size of window?

Comment: @RezaAghaei i used the windows size is 1386, 596,start position is center position

Comment: And how did you set the window to be center? Please share your code and settings. By sharing codes and settings you would receive more effective helps.

Comment: @RezaAghaei In form load event i called another form like this way      private void frmmainmenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1(this);
            form.ShowDialog();} and if you remove this form1 calling event i'll get the status bar above the task bar

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't help reproduce the problem. Please your code to the question. Also Let us know how you set size and position of `Form1` :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Size-1386, 596. Start position-center screen,windows state-maximized

Comment: Dose this problem occur only with this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size-1386, 596. 
Start position-center screen.
windows state-maximized
set Maximize box true